# Flushing all current figures in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I did

```
figure(1)
plot(...)
figure(2)
plot(...)
```

and I want to create a third figure and show only that one. so that:

```
figure(1)
plot(...)
figure(2)
plot(...)
somemagicFuncToFlushFigures()
figure(3)
plot(...)
show()
```

will only show the third figure.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to close the figures right? I wonder if the following helps?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close()
```

**UPDATE**:
As @jorgeca says, to close all the figures try using `plt.close('all')`

Comment: That only closes the active figure. I think the OP wants `plt.close('all')`.

Comment: both `close()` and `close('all')` did not worked for me